# SQL Server query to C# Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I'm currently having a rough time converting my SQL query to LINQ for a school project I'm using WPF and Entity Framework

here is my SQL query (working exactly as I expect)

```
select IngrediantName,sum(IngrediantQuantity) as Quantity, IngrediantMeasurementUnit from Users
join Shopping_List
on Users.UserID = Shopping_List.ShoppingListID
join List_Item
on List_Item.ShoppingListID = Shopping_List.ShoppingListID
join Ingrediant
on Ingrediant.IngrediantID = List_Item.IngrediantID
where Users.UserID = 1
group by IngrediantName,IngrediantMeasurementUnit
```

Here is the query that I have so far

```
var query = from user in dbContext.Users
                        join shoppingList in dbContext.ShoppingLists on user.UserId equals shoppingList.UserId
                        join listItem in dbContext.ListItems on shoppingList.ShoppingListId equals listItem.ShoppingListId
                        join ingrediant in dbContext.Ingrediants on listItem.IngrediantId equals ingrediant.IngrediantId
                        where currentUserNumber == user.UserId
                        
                        select new
                        {
                            name = ingrediant.IngrediantName,
                            quantity = ingrediant.IngrediantQuantity,
                            unit = ingrediant.IngrediantMeasurementUnit,
                        };
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
            var query = from user in dbContext.Users
                        join shoppingList in dbContext.ShoppingLists on user.UserId equals shoppingList.UserId
                        join listItem in dbContext.ListItems on shoppingList.ShoppingListId equals listItem.ShoppingListId
                        join ingrediant in dbContext.Ingrediants on listItem.IngrediantId equals ingrediant.IngrediantId
                        where currentUserNumber == user.UserId
                        group ingrediant by ingrediant.IngrediantQuantity into x
                        
                        select new
                        {
                            name = x.GroupBy(x => x.IngrediantName),
                            quantity = x.Sum(x => x.IngrediantQuantity),
                            unit = x.GroupBy(x => x.IngrediantMeasurementUnit),
                        };
```

this one return the following error which doesn't tell much

> Argument type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.TransparentIdentifierFactory+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.TransparentIdentifierFactory+TransparentIdentifier`2

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, if you need more info I will provide it for sure

Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to do i saw a lot of example online but only with one join

Comment: Sure i will update with what i try so far

Comment: It's not supposed to be this hard, by the way. EF is a device that is supposed to know how your entities relate and it will do joins for you; you don't take an SQL approach of writing all the query out for it; it's intended that you can eg `dbContext.Ingredients.Where(i => i.List.ShoppingListId == 1).GroupBy(i => new { i.IngredientName, i.IngredientMeasurementUnit }).Select(g => new { g.Key.IngredientName, g.Key.IngredientMeasurementUnit, g.Sum(i =>i.IngredientQuantity) })`

Comment: Seems like you don't need to join users or shopping list btw

Comment: Mmm thanks for this approach this seem way more like it should be do you mind posting this a an answer so I can mark it as a correct one?

Comment: I can't be sure that the column names/property names are fully correct - I just guessed at some things - but you could take the suggestion and try/tweak it to see how it works for you and then post it up as an answer yourself :)

Comment: Trying it rigth now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

I got this working here the answers to the question for anyone else

```cs
var query = 
    from user in dbContext.Users
    join shoppingList in dbContext.ShoppingLists 
        on user.UserId equals shoppingList.UserId
    join listItem in dbContext.ListItems 
        on shoppingList.ShoppingListId equals listItem.ShoppingListId
    join ingrediant in dbContext.Ingrediants 
        on listItem.IngrediantId equals ingrediant.IngrediantId
    where currentUserNumber == user.UserId
    group ingrediant by new { name = ingrediant.IngrediantName, unit = ingrediant.IngrediantMeasurementUnit } into x
    select new
    {
        name = x.Key.name,
        quantity = x.Sum(x => x.IngrediantQuantity),
        unit = x.Key.unit,
    };
```

if you look at the group line
`group ingrediant by new { name = ingrediant.IngrediantName, unit = ingrediant.IngrediantMeasurementUnit } into x`

from my understanding you use the new to create a new selector then you can use x.key.name and x.key.unit where name and unit are simply some variable